# Не работает infavorites:mine

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, избранное

При вводе в поиск [infavorites:mine](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine) не выводится ничего, хотя я добавлял в избранное вопросы.

Comment: Имхо, есть смысл написать на [meta.se]. Проблема глобальная, как я понимаю.

Comment: Отметился пока в [чате](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6339291#6339291) на этот счёт.

Comment: @alexolut "есть смысл написать на Meta Stack Exchange" - написал: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300909/infavoritesmine-search-query-does-not-work

Comment: [Уже исправлено](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300917/370389)